# Selectively passing kwargs in boto3 calls

Tags: python, python-3.x, boto3, keyword-argument

Is there a way to selectively pass kw arguments on a boto3 call based on the value of the variable?

For example, in a function call
`client.update_server(ServerId=server_id, Protocols=protocols, SecurityPolicyName=policy)`

if protocols is empty/None, my call should be
`client.update_server(ServerId=server_id, SecurityPolicyName=policy)`

And if policy is empty/None my call should be
`client.update_server(ServerId=server_id, Protocols=protocols)`

Is this possible to do in python (3.7x)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `kwargs` as you mention. Just create a helper function and parse the originally passed in `kwargs` to filter out the `None` values. After all, `kwargs` is just a dictionary.

```
def update_server(client, **kwargs):
    new_kwargs = {k: v, for k, v in kwargs.items() if v is not None}
    client.update_server(**new_kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Take out the "," between v and for.

```
new_kwargs = {k: v, for k, v in kwargs.items() if v is not None}
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Like This

```
def update_server(client, **kwargs):
    new_kwargs = {k: v for k, v in kwargs.items() if v is not None}
    client.update_server(**new_kwargs)
```